# While Loop doesn't recognize multiple conditions

Tags: python, while-loop, user-input

I am asking for an input from the user and it has to be a single character alphabet.

I tried this code.

```
ask = ''
while len(ask) != 1 and ask.isalpha() != True:
    ask = input(message).upper()
```

But this accepts any single number digit to break out of the while loop. I don't understand why.

I checked the `ask.isalpha()` on that single number and that returns False. So why does it break out of the loop.

Sorry for this question. This is very naïve but I couldn't find an answer.

Thank you.

Edit:
Added the whole code.

Comment: you need `==` instead of `!=` with the second part of condition. also, consider using `do.. while` loop to allow the first input.

Comment: I am sorry, but the `==` doesn't work for me. The loop doesn't even start and there's no prompt for use input after changing to `==`.

Comment: the while loop is failing as `ask` fails to satisfy the loop criteria. set `ask` to some default value say `a` or use `do.. while` loop as suggested.

Comment: Sorry @KrishnaChaurasia But pls explain this do-while loop. I am not able to find any such loop for python.

Comment: my bad...python doesn't support `do.. while` loop. https://stackoverflow.com/a/65840480/5147259 should solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You need an `or` operation and not `and` to achieve what you want. Also, you need to take user input first time before entering the `while` loop.

So your code should be:

```
ask = input(message).upper()
while len(ask) != 1 or ask.isalpha() != True:
    ask = input(message).upper()
```

Comment: I am sorry, but the `==` doesn't work for me. The loop doesn't even start and there's no prompt for use input after changing to `==`.

Comment: @Meet Edited my answer, try again

Comment: I tried this. Entered 1 for the first input prompt. And the program stopped.

Comment: it should stop since `1.isalpha()` is `False`.

Comment: But I need the input to be a 1 character alphabet only. '1' is not an alphabet so requirement is to ask for input again.

Comment: @U11-Forward Exactly. So the requirement is: if user enters a non-alphabet, ask for user input again till they enter a single alphabet.

Comment: @Meet Oh check my answer out again!

Comment: @U11-Forward Yes. This did it. Can you explain why that works and starting with `ask = ''` doesn't work?

Comment: @Meet It works because I use `or` not `and`. `and` checks if both conditions are true and `or` checks for only one. If it's good remember to accept and upvote :)

Comment: No @U11-Forward I am not asking about or/and. I am saying that that while line works (whether we need or / and) only when we put the input line before while. In my question, I had simply started with defining the variable ask as `ask = ''`. In which case, even with correct or/and statement in while loop, it didn't work. So why's that?

Comment: @Meet It's because the `while` line has a condition using the `ask` variable. If it isn't defined, it would give a `NameError`. You need to do the input before as the fist input so that the `while` line can condition the `ask` input.

Comment: I'm sorry but that isn't the correct answer. Contrary to that, I have already defined the `ask` variable before the while loop begins. The issue should be something relating to interpreting the `''` value of the variable for the loop condition.

Comment: You might want to run the code that I initially shared to find an answer my question. That code didn't run into any error. Just that the condition wasn't checked for the loop. So something more technical is happening here.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `!=` which stand for not equal to so when you enter 1 digit number condition for `while` loop doesn't match so code stops. You should use `==` instead of `!=`.

Comment: I am sorry, but the `==` doesn't work for me. The loop doesn't even start and there's no prompt for use input after changing to `==`.

Answer (score 0):

There is different way to do it

```py
# if you want user to enter upper case
while True:
    ask = input('message: ')
    if len(ask) == 1 and ask.isalpha() == True and ask.isupper() == True:
       break
       
# if you want to convert input to upper
while True:
    ask = (input('message: ')).upper()
    if len(ask) == 1 and ask.isalpha() == True:
       break
```

is this case all your condition are satisfied,

Comment: this is overcomplicated and doesn't really provide a solution to the question. other answers are more clear

Comment: please enlight me what i'm doing wrong, the question specify the need of single alpha character to break the loop, with the  given the condition.